# Can't use Gatling Expression Language inside my own code/functions

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm creating one report for all simulations in SCALA, in part of them I don't have all attributes and I need to replace that because I'm getting no attribute defined error.

I was trying below code and many many more:

`val dbc_communityID = if ("${communityID.exists()}" == true) "${communityID}" else "N/A"`

I always have "N/A". I also checked

> == 1

> == "true"

I spend definitely to much time of that,
Please help

Comment: What's the type of `communityID`? `Option[String]`? Ah, no, it can't be `Option[String]`, because that has no `.exists()` method. What's the type of `communityID`?

Comment: It's Char, previously taked from flat file in few places I used to convert it to String. More u can see at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573366/gatling-tests-results-on-postgresql on second block of code, now we just don't have session.

Comment: I don't understand at all what the `"${communityID.exists()}"` is doing in this context. The only thing you can do with it is to pass it to one of the Gatling DSL-methods. Why did it end up inside of an ordinary `if`-`else`, who or what is supposed to interpret it? How is this Gatling-Expression-Language snippet supposed to be interpreted, if there is no Gatling interpreter anywhere in sight? Please reformulate your question so that the context is clear, otherwise the answerers are just wasting their time trying to guess what the `.exists()` gizmo is supposed to mean.

Comment: Please add the `gatling` tag next time you ask a question about Gatling.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [Gatling](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/) official documentation:

> This Expression Language only works on String values being passed to Gatling DSL
> methods. Such Strings are parsed only once, when the Gatling
> simulation is being instantiated.
>
> For example queryParam("latitude", session => "${latitude}") wouldn’t
> work because the parameter is not a String, but a function that
> returns a String.
>
> Also, queryParam("latitude", "${latitude}".toInt) wouldn’t because the
> toInt would happen before passing the parameter to the queryParam
> method.
>
> The solution here would be to pass a function:
>
> session => session("latitude").validate[Int].

In short: you can't mix Gatling EL and functions/custom code. If you want to implement some custom logic that deals with Session data, you have to use the [Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/session_api/), eg:

```scala
session => session("communityID").asOption[String].getOrElse("N/A")
```

Comment: Trust me i tried make that in session, result set u can see at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573366/gatling-tests-results-on-postgresql) but thanks to You, I have an idea to push session param out to make them use for exec(jdbc).

Comment: @Oskiii The problem is you don't provide any context as to where the original `communityID` comes from (feeder? check?) and where you want to use the dbc_communityID result (in your own code? to be passed to Gatling components?). Depending on your use case, the best place to have this code differs.

Answer (score -2):

```
if ("${communityID.exists()}" == true)
```

You are comparing a fixed `String` with a `Boolean` so the result will always be `false`. There is probably a compiler warning about this.

It is possible that you want this, but hard to say without know more about the rest of the code:

```
if (s"${communityID.exists()}" == "true")
```

But in that case it is simpler to write

```
if (communityID.exists())
```

Comment: The first 6 lines contain two bad code snippets and meta-comments about the doubts about the meaning of the question, only the last line contains some useful code. I think it could be shortened considerably to the relevant information, in order to attempt to make it more useful for future readers. Or maybe at least move the correct line a bit further up, and defer the discussion of hypothetical error scenarios to the second part of the answer.

Comment: First sample brings, not found: value communityID, second one same. Based on https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/ code should be in double quotes. Im lost.